# Ionic Framework Mobile Application not updating

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, socket.io, ionic-framework

I created an android application using `ionic framework` and `socket.io` . When I tried to serve it in the browser (laptop and mobile) it works. BTW, it's just a basic realtime photo upload. I use my wifi address `192.168.15.2:8000` since my backend (node listens to port `8000`). My problem is when I build the application and install the apk to my android phone, realtime upload is not working. It the mobile (apk) can upload but it is not syncing to my laptop. But when I try again using the mobile browser, it's working perfectly. How can I fix this? or do I need to change the IP address?

```
angular.module('com.htmlxprs.imageShare.services',[]).value('USER',{}).value('SOCKET_URL','192.168.15.2:8000');
```

Comment: show your code please..

Comment: I already already added the code to my question.